# How to prevent unauthorized saves to database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I'm building a simple clicker game to be played online.

The game saves clicks to my database by executing an Ajax post call to a php script.

Now I'm trying to figure out how I could limit the post submits from my server only so people couldn't cheat by just sending their own scores straight to the database by posting.

I tried limiting posts to my server IP or localhost but that doesn't work as Ajax post uses the users own IP and not the servers IP to post. So I wasn't able to post even from my own server anymore after that.

I'm saving the clicks to localstorage which I know is another place where people could cheat.

What could I do to only allow the posts from my server?

Comment: Is the game open to anyone without login?

Comment: Is the game written in javascript ?

Comment: Can you explain the mechanics of the game a bit more? Does localstorage just keep track of a single, incrementing number? And at some point, this is posted to the server?

Comment: It's a good question that I've thought about for a while and all the solutions I've come up with seem to have an anti solution. The best approach may be to use `Code Obfuscation` or better use **WebPack** so that the client side code can be hard to read.

Comment: Yes the game is open to anyone without login. Game is written in Javascript.  Localstorage keeps track of incrementsl clicks and the Ajax call funs every 10 seconds to send the clicks to database (10 second counter is reset back to 10 seconds on each click so the player needs to be without any clicks for 10 seconds to trigger the Ajax call. After successful post the localstorage data is reset to 0. Code Obfuscation might solve the localstorage issue but I still need to deny post calls from outside the game somehow

Answer (score 0):

One cheat-proof solution would be to make the server increment the clicks while user/player only send an info about an action - like in a multiplayer game.

You would need a web-socket connection to the server and treat each connection/socket as an individual player.

One easy solution would be to use Node.js backend + socket.io library.